# 15.10 very slow during file operations, despite 16GB RAM good CPU and no apps running

Tags: 15.10, performance

Every time I move or extract a big file (example: 1GB), or when I delete a directory containing a lot of small files, Ubuntu becomes extremely slow: the mouse stops moving (or only moves after a minute), Firefox greys out, the System Monitor indicator only refreshes once in a while.

It is a brand new [Lenovo Thinkpad T550](http://shop.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/t-series/t550/) with 16GB RAM and a good CPU. Yesterday I freshly installed Ubuntu 2015.10 with all default settings, then I only installed a few apps, configured a few Unity tweaks, and put a 360GB backup file in $HOME.

Right now I am trying to uncompress the 360GB backup file with the following command:

```
nice -n 19 tar xf backup.tar
```

... which makes the system absolutely unusable. I had opened `top` and `iotop` before running the command, it refreshes every few minutes, here is a picture:

[image]

What did I do wrong?
Can I fix the problem with a few kernel settings or by removing the swap?

*I also use 2015.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T520 and it works perfectly (10GB RAM, 16GB swap).*

Answer (score 0):

If you have an HDD, try the CFQ I/O scheduler. Here's how to do it:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash elevator=cfq"
```

Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

For more explanation google "enable cfq in ubuntu".

Comment: Yes HDD. Is there any risk to doing that, or is it totally safe? What are the reasons why it is not enabled by default?

Comment: By default ubuntu comes with deadline IO scheduler, which is optimized for SSD's, not HDD's. There aren't any known risks of switching to CFQ, only that you'll get a lower performance in SSD.

Comment: I have modified and updated then rebooted, I will let you know, thanks!